# How to extract a javascript variable using regular expression

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I need to extract a javascript variable containing a multiline JSON from a remote page using a python script(2.7), and I want to use regex to do this, but my pattern does not return anything

What am I doing wrong ?

here's my code :

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://somesite.com/affiliates/")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
affiliates = re.findall('#var affiliates = (.*?);\s*$#m', result.read())
print affiliates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [`re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall), you'll see you need to change how you're using it

```
affiliates = re.findall('var affiliates = (.*?);\s*$', result.read(), re.M)
```

You might also want to consider how whitespace can be sloppy in *JavaScript*.